# Find mismatch between two rows using SQL

Tags: sql

I have an sql query which will give two rows with 400+ columns. I have to compare each column and find if there are any mismatches.

I used Excel formla `=IF(A2=A3,"TRUE","FALSE")` to do this and show TRUE or FALSE values in the third row. How do i do the same with SQL?

Comment: You would use a case expression, although comparing columns and comparing a column over different *rows* like your title suggests are different things.

Comment: Add row identifier (for example `row1` and `row2`) to each row, unpivot all the columns and pivot the attribute value back by that row identifier. It will show you two values per attribute name which you may filter later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rows are from the same table:

```
select * from some_table where cond1
minus (/except)
select * from some_table where cond2
```

cond1 is where condition for fetching the first row

cond2 is where condition for fetching the second row

some_table in your case is sql query -> **Note in some databases you need to give a name for that nested query**

```
select * from (your_query) q where cond1
minus (/except)
select * from (your_query) q where cond2
```

minus (/except) -> in some databases this operation is called minus, and in the others is called except

You will see the result if rows are different!

**Note that if you want to do minus(except) you need same number and datatype of columns**